# JMeter to wait until form is fully loaded

Tags: jmeter

I have a form, which is inside a `div` on page. When page is loaded, form start to load with a loading screen. `JMeter` capture it, when page is loaded, it doesn't wait for the form, so page loader is on 0 % when I view results. I tried to use `Constant Timer` to delay processing. `JMeter` says too early in this case, that request is successful, because a failure can happen during loading of input fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMeter waits for the whole response with one little exception, as per JMeter project main page:

> JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. **In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages**. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

So if your form is being loaded via [AJAX request](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) JMeter won't automatically execute it, you will have to add a separate [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler to invoke the relevant AJAX request(s) which will load your form.

In order to mimic real browser's behavior you can put the main and the "AJAX" requests under [Parallel Controller](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md#parallel-controller) (you can install it using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager))

[image: JMeter Parallel Sampler]